# rawQuery in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database in my application. I want to select specific rows. 
here is my query string :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String C_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID = category_id;
String TABLE_PRODUCT = tblProduct;
String categoryID = 1;

String select = String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s=%s",
    C_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID, TABLE_PRODUCT, C_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID,
    categoryID);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select,new String[]{});
```

the cursor c is empty! what when i use the .db file on device with sqlite editor and run

```
SELECT category_id FROM tblProduct WHERE category_id=1
```

it returns 2 rows.
whats wrong? please help me!

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be what you're actually using as it has syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use database's query method as,

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCT, null, C_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID+"=?", new String[]{categoryID}, null, null, null);
```

Hope this works well for you !!

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String categoryID = 1;
String select = "SELECT category_id FROM tblProduct WHERE category_id="+categoryID;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select,new String[]{});
```

Just use this

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to put the ' and ' after "="; I mean:

```
String select = String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s='%s'",
    C_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID, TABLE_PRODUCT, C_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID,
    categoryID);
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select,null);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

> Cursor c = dB. rawQuery (select, null);